# Why can't I rename folder or create it with special character?

Tags: bash, character, special-characters

<s>I want to rename folder or create it with special character of question mark (?)</s>

I can create a folder with name '????????" by gnome file manger

[image]

but I can't create the same folder by bash and with command-line

Why can'n I ?

> I can create any folder with any name by visual file manager, But by bash can't it.

[image]

```
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin#
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin# mkdir test
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin# cd test/
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# touch abc
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# ls
abc
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# mkdir ???
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: File exists
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# mkdir ????
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘????’: Invalid argument
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# mkdir '????'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘????’: Invalid argument
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# mkdir '\?\?\?\?'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘\\?\\?\\?\\?’: Invalid argument
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# mkdir \?\?\?\?
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘????’: Invalid argument
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test# mkdir "\?\?\?\?"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘\\?\\?\\?\\?’: Invalid argument
root@k-five:/media/shu/winlin/test#
```

---

> ## Sorry everyone, I made a mistake . My problem is solved by :

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda4 /media/$USER/fat32 -o    uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022
```

<s>So I change ownership of root to me and I can run command without sudo,but I can't create "??????" folder name yet, because it's vFAT partition & that one it's NTFS</s>

If you have FAT partition don't try to create name of folder with special character.End :))))))))

Comment: try escaping `mkdir \?\?\?\?\?\?\?\?`

Comment: I try it :( and does't work

Comment: In my case escaping the characters worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a file with the same number of characters in its filename in the directory already and you forgot to escape the [wildcard characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character).

```
mkdir '??????'
```

Comment: No,it's example. I delete that folder and try to create by bash, but I can't

Answer (score 2):

maybe your on a root folder and you forgot the enter the `sudo` command 
for root user privileges?

`sudo mkdir ?????`

Comment: on escaped characters leave the quotes out. `# mkdir \?\?\?\?` instead of `# mkdir '\?\?\?\?'`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate the scenario and it worked like a charm in bash.

1. Created one test directory

   ```
   [root@localhost ~]# cd test/
   ```
2. Created one empty file

   ```
   [root@localhost test]# touch mysql
   [root@localhost test]# ls
   mysql
   ```
3. Now I tried creating a file with name `?????` but it does not allow me. By looking at the error message it is clear that it is complaining of file exists error message. I have one mysql file which has same number of character in the file name as that of the file that I want to create.

   ```
   [root@localhost test]# mkdir ?????
   mkdir: cannot create directory ‘mysql’: File exists
   ```
4. Let's create the folder by placing the filename inside single quotes

   ```
   [root@localhost test]# mkdir '?????'
   ```
5. Let's verify. This time folder got successfully created.

   ```
   [root@localhost test]# ls
   ?????  mysql
   ```
6. You can try escaping the special characters as well to create the file/folder as given below

   ```
   [root@localhost test]# mkdir \?\?\?\?\?\?\?
   [root@localhost test]# ls
   ?????  ???????  mysql
   ```

Comment: I test it, But no :(

Comment: Can you take an empty directory and follow my step by step approach? It should definitely work.

Comment: can you paste the bash and os distribution version?

Comment: yes sure++++++++++ Ubuntu 15.04+++++++++                                                                                                     bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: I am able to create the file/directory using the same os and bash version in docker. In your case I think we are missing something.

Comment: I mistake,sorry :( +++++++++ thank you for your help